# best way to implement an admin panel in nodeJS with express

Tags: node.js, express

I am making a blog application with nodeJS and express. I want to implement an admin panel which I can create,delete, update and edit my posts, but I don't know how can I keep those admin routes secret and what kind of authentication to make. Do I make a collection on the db with only one row (mongodb) with the admin password, or keep the password I want for the admin authentication on a separate file? Is this secure enough? Should I just keep the password I want on a if statement on the code? I'm gonna be the only person to use this system but I want to understand the best way to keep it secure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I prefer segregating request patterns and defining separate auth mechanisms for them. For example...

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const basicAuth = require('express-basic-auth');


app.use('/web/*', basicAuth({
    users: authKeys
}));

app.use('/restrict/*', basicAuth({
    users: adminAuthKeys
}));
```

...any normal user visiting my site over `/web/*` has separate authentication defined than the admins who would visit the site over `/restrict/*`. `authKeys` contain the user authentication keys and `adminAuthKeys` contain the admin authentication keys. I can then define the routes for each of them as required. For example...

```
// For user
app.get('/web/profile', (req, res) => {
    ...
    ...
});

// For user
app.get('/web/post/:id', (req, res) => {
    ...
    ...
});

// For admin
app.get('/restrict/stats', (req, res) => {
    ...
    ...
});

// For admin
app.get('/restrict/dashboard', (req, res) => {
    ...
    ...
});
```

Here I have shown the example with `express-basic-auth`, you may try whichever authentication mechanism suits best for you. We wouldn't usually store passwords in files which you would commit in your repository. Passwords are best stored in a secured database with proper encoding in place. For this `express-basic-auth` example, if you can initialise JSON objects of the schema...

```
const authKeys = {
    "some-user-name": "some-password",
    "another-user-name": "another-password",
    ...
    ...
}

const adminAuthKeys = {
    "some-admin-name": "some-password",
    "another-admin-name": "another-password",
    ...
    ...
}
```

...by fetching the data from your storage during app start-up and then initialise the `app.use()` blocks for users and admins as shown defining `basicAuth` with `express`, I think it should work fine.

Hope this helps :)